# .Net comunication between Matlab and C++

Tags: c++, .net, matlab

I have two different process, one in Matlab and one in C++ under a Windows machine. Actually, I am working to develop a communication between them and, now, I am trying to use the .net APIs.

As a matter of fact, C++ has a main thread that acquire in input a set of data and, according to the input, do stuffs (in other threads) and wait for another input. Matlab has the main task to provide automatically the different inputs and, after that, return the output.

Here the simplified version:

**C++**

```
#include "main.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string m = "";

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    while (true)
    {
        std::cin >> m;
        std::cout << "command: " << m << "\n";
    }
}
```

that produce "myecho.exe"

**Matlab**

```
echoTest = 'myecho.exe';

proc = System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = echoTest;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.Start();

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine('test1')
proc.StandardInput.Flush
while proc.StandardOutput.Peek ~= -1
    disp(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine);
end

pause(1)

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine('test2')
proc.StandardInput.Flush
while proc.StandardOutput.Peek ~= -1
    disp(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine);
end

pause(1)

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine('test3')
proc.StandardInput.Flush
while proc.StandardOutput.Peek ~= -1
    disp(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine);
end
```

Unfortunately, Matlab is able to send only the first Input and collect the first output. However, the second input/output does not produce any results (peek = -1). Consequentially, the Matlab result is:

```
>>command: test1

>>
```

Have you any idea regarding this strange behavior?!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do... You want to call C++ code from Matlab or call Matlab from C++ ? And then what .NET has to do with that ?

Comment: stdin and stdout is probably not the right way to communicate with another process. Do you have access to the source code of the C++ program? Turning it into a MEX-file would probably be the most robust approach. But you can also turn things around, and control MATLAB from your C++ program using MATLAB Engine.

Comment: @bricx The Matlab provide inputs to C++ and collect the outputs (like in the echo sw written before). .Net is the libraries used in Matlab to manage the C++ sw, or I missed something?

Comment: @Cris Luengo, Nope, the C++ code is locked, and it cannot be touched (actually, I do not have the source code). It waits for an input on the command line and, consequentially, provide an output.

Comment: If you don’t have the program’s sources, it being C++ is irrelevant. You have a binary executable that works in a given way, and you need to interact with it. It’s a shitty situation. Sorry and good luck!

Comment: Maybe add a little pause between writing and reading? Or wait until there is something to read in the first place?

Comment: And do you have access to the .NET code? I am assuming it's just a wrapper around the C++... Maybe try to make it work in .NET first and then call the .NET library from Matlab.